# Combine three tables to make an updatable new table

Tags: mysql, join, datatables, union

Is there any way (except views) to create a new table in mysql that combines data from three or more different tables and when inserting new records into the initial tables data are also displayed in the new merged table?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Introduction

One thing though except for views, would be to use triggers.
When an update is made on this new table, your `on insert` or `on update` triggers could call a stored procedure to update the related data.

### How to Pages:

See the following related pages:

- [mysql after insert trigger which updates another table's column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16892070/mysql-after-insert-trigger-which-updates-another-tables-column)
- [Using an update trigger to update another table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7404805/using-an-update-trigger-to-update-another-table)
- [Update another table after insert using a trigger?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18264992/update-another-table-after-insert-using-a-trigger)